# Mark an app as publisher verified in Azure AD B2C

Tags: azure-active-directory, azure-ad-b2c

I have an Azure AD B2C directory with a registered app that I wish to mark as "publisher verified". I followed the steps in these documents:

- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/publisher-verification-overview
- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/mark-app-as-publisher-verified

However, when I go to the app's "Branding" page, there is no option called "Add MPN ID to verify publisher".

- I have an MPN ID for a valid Microsoft Partner Network account
- The app has a Publisher Domain configured
- I am logged in with a Global Admin account
- I log in with multi-factor authentication

As far as I can see all the requirements to get publisher verified are met, but the option isn't even there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The documents you are refering to is related to Azure AD tenant. The Publisher domains are not supported for Azure AD B2C app registrations.

> Publisher domain verification - Your app is registered on
> .onmicrosoft.com, which isn't a verified domain. Additionally, the
> publisher domain is primarily used for granting user consent, which
> doesn't apply to Azure AD B2C apps for user authentication

Please refer the [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/app-registrations-training-guide#features-not-applicable-in-azure-ad-b2c-tenants) for more information.

Comment: Hi, thank you for the answer. I now understand that I am very confused about the whole system.

My app is not registered on .onmicrosoft.com, it has a Publisher domain, which is the URL where our end users access our application. And we definitely ask for user consent during log in... So it makes me very confused that the documentation says this "doesn't apply to Azure AD B2C apps".

My problem case is a customer who have the "Users can consent to apps from verified publishers" option selected in their AD, which is why I am trying to get our app marked as verified publisher.

Comment: Figured it out. For our case you have to create the app in a standard AD since this is not supported in B2C.

Comment: @ViliusKazakauskas I'm working on an iOS/macOS app that integrates Outlook and I'm just like you were, very confused about the whole process to get my app publisher verified. My app is registered and I also created a B2C tenant but I'm not sure how to tie this all up. What do you mean by creating the app in a standard AD? Thank you.

Comment: @rs7 it's been a while so hard to remember. But I believe the solution was to register the app in a different tenant, which was not a B2C tenant. Then proceed with the whole verification process.